# How can I set the output directory of xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

When I run xcodebuild the output directory is set to:
/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-fybdjyuardwltihdwcfbwmguufrw/Build/Products/

How can I manually set the output directory of xcodebuild?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: So I can deploy the artefacts as part of a maven build

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify `-archivePath` command line option. If works from version 5+.

This location is also available under `ARCHIVE_PATH` variable in a defined post build under archive action in xcode.